# Meta query with compare by more than 2 fields

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, meta-value

i have 5 sets of meta boxes in some custom postype. So.. i know how to compare two meta box values...

**Example:**

```
'meta_query'        => array(
    'relation'  => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => THEME_PREF.'source_lang_1',
        'value'   => $sourceLang,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => THEME_PREF.'target_lang_1',
        'value'   => $targetLang,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
),
```

**But...**
what if i need to check 4 fields - the verification isnt true..
meaning it doesnt returnes **only the right results**
only "posts" that answer both conditions.

```
$transargs = array(
    'post_type'         =>  'translators',
    'orderby'           =>  'date',
    'order'             =>  'DESC',
    'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       =>  THEME_PREF.'source_lang_1',
                'value'     =>  $sourceLang,
                'compare'   =>  '='
            ),
            array(
                'key'       =>  THEME_PREF.'target_lang_1',
                'value'     =>  $targetLang,
                'compare'   =>  '='
            )
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       =>  THEME_PREF.'source_lang_2',
                'value'     =>  $sourceLang,
                'compare'   =>  '='
            ),
            array(
                'key'       =>  THEME_PREF.'target_lang_2',
                'value'     =>  $targetLang,
                'compare'   =>  '='
            )
        ),
    )   
);
$trns_query = new WP_Query($transargs);
```

**To elaborate**
i get a lot of results where the first condition of each meta query is met but not the second one and thus the relation and

Example:
$sourceLang = 1;
$targetLang = 2;

**i might also get**
*(which is not good... the AND doesnt work?)...*
result that equals  $sourcelang(1) / targetLang(5)

Comment: Your code looks proper for the 4 post meta query. Could you please explain what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: do you mean this would work as i? this is just the example code of what am trying to achieve...  Would run to test it now.

Comment: it doesnt return the right results... the compare doesnt work or i dont understand how to verify both condition...

Comment: Nested relations among subset of meta queries are possible on  WP 4.1 that will be released next week. See [trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29642). Consider to use beta version.

Comment: thats cool #G.M so, this is currently not supported in wp. i see, i cant use the beta, my WP is in hebrew. Thanks a lot for this info. Submit as answer to claim the reward ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested relations among subset of meta queries are possible on WP 4.1 that is planned to be releaded next coming [December 10, 2014](https://wordpress.org/about/roadmap/). See [trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29642).

So wait a few days or use the beta version.